# JQUERY LIVE Confirm issue

Tags: jquery, confirm

My issue is relating to dynamically applied elements to a page that I am running a confirm against. The code correctly targets the element and asks the confirmation part, however the problem is if I select Yes, I have no idea where the return value is hidden, it is not set in the class like my thoughts below, nor does it return a value of sorts.

Anyone know how I can get some form of return value from the confirm for the element that I wish to delete?

```
    $('.deleteMe').live('click', function() {

        confirmFunction(this);
        if ($(this).hasClass('confirm')){ alert("yea");} else {alert("no");}
    });

    function confirmFunction(element) {
        $(element).confirm({
          msg:'Confirm Action!<br />',
          stopAfter:'ok',
          eventType:'click',
          timeout:5000,
          buttons: { ok:'Yes', cancel:'No', separator:' - '}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the examples on the plug-in page, it should be like this:

Assign the click handler that should run if confirmation is successful, then assign the confirm plugin.

```
 $('.deleteMe').live('click',function() {
    // Code here for when they click YES on the confirm box.
    // This only executes in 2 scenarios, either the item was clicked
    //   and the confirm plugin was not active, or it was active and
    //   the user selected Yes.
 });

 function updateConfirms() {
    $('.deleteMe').confirm({
      msg:'Confirm Action!<br />',
      stopAfter:'ok',
      eventType:'click',
      timeout:5000,
      buttons: { ok:'Yes', cancel:'No', separator:' - '}
    });
 }

 updateConfirms();
```

Due to the dynamic nature you mentioned, you would need to call updateConfirms() after adding new elements that need confirmations.

EDIT:  Let's try not using Live, and refreshing the click handler and the confirm after any additions:

```
 function updateConfirms() {
   $('.deleteMe').click(function() {
    // Code here for when they click YES on the confirm box.
    // This only executes in 2 scenarios, either the item was clicked
    //   and the confirm plugin was not active, or it was active and
    //   the user selected Yes.
   });

   $('.deleteMe').confirm({
     msg:'Confirm Action!<br />',
     stopAfter:'ok',
     eventType:'click',
     timeout:5000,
     buttons: { ok:'Yes', cancel:'No', separator:' - '}
   });
 }

 updateConfirms();
```

Comment: Hi, I have attempted what you have said unfortunately it does not seem to link with the delete method. I am adding the called elements, then running the function as you instruct, it doesn't however seem to add the confirm handler to the .deleteMe elements. As soon as i click the deleteMe element it goes straight into the alert hello call instead of confirming.

Comment: @John Ok, Maybe it's the 'live' part that is causing a problem.  I'll post a quick modification.

Comment: @John try the second approach I just posted and let me know.

Comment: Who ever you are you are a legend.